# My code is not giving the desired output

Tags: c#

My text file has the following information

```
   Names                     Date Of Birth        Date Of Joining   
   Bella Swan                01/18/1986           12/12/2012
   Edward Cullen             10/13/1983           05/08/2013
   Jacob Black               10/18/1981           12/12/2012
   Carlisle Cullen           05/08/1953           12/16/1998
   Alice Cullen              01/18/1986           09/09/2009
```

If the user enters a date, all the records relevant to the date should be pulled up.
The user enters the date 01/18/1986
The Display shows the following details:

```
      Bella Swan                01/18/1986           12/12/2012
      Alice Cullen              01/18/1986           09/09/2009
```

If the user enters the date 12/12/2012

```
       Bella Swan                01/18/1986           12/12/2012
       Jacob Black               10/18/1981           12/12/2012
```

The guidelines I need to abide by is not to work with jagged arrays, linq, List, Exception, etc.

I don't know how to get the above output.
I tried this but it didn't work.

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The Date");
    string Date = Console.ReadLine();
    string line = null;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("Scheduler.txt", FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);
    {
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(Date))
            {   
                Console.WriteLine(Date);
                break; // then stop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "it didn't work" is not much of a problem statement.

Comment: So what happens instead of the desired output?

Comment: Firstly, you're only printing the matching date, not the whole line. You're also stopping after the first match.

Comment: You need to validate your input (turn it into a DateTime) and then format that in the exact format as in the data.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Eh, give the guy a break. He stated his expected output. He gave us code that isn't that hard to figure out what is going on. I admit that the question could and should have been better posed, and said *as much* in my answer. But I think the strict "every question was be perfectly and precisely stated" stuff is just out of control. It's a *question* and *answer* site. Questions *generally* come from people that don't know what they are doing (not all, *generally*). So, people that don't know what they are doing ask questions, so expect meh. You're here to answer and learn, no?

Comment: @Jason - No, questions do not have to be perfect but an OP should at least be told about very glaring omissions. That's good for the site and for the OP. The downvotes are a bit undeserved but then again, this question was asked before today. By the OP or a classmate.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing this?

```
Console.WriteLine(Date);
```

You need to print the whole line:

```
Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Why are you doing this?

```
break; // then stop
```

You're stopping prematurely before you've read the whole file; remove it so that you continue looping until you reach the end of the file.

Other possible problem: Did you check to make sure your input was actually a valid date? One way would be like this:

```
DateTime valid; 
if(!DateTime.TryParse(Date, "MM/dd/YYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) {
    // handle invalid date format
}
```

Beyond that, this is actually a pretty good start. You're on the right approach.

However, your question was terribly posed. Next time, state the actual, concrete problem that you're having. You might even find that articulating the issue will help you understand your own code better so you can find the mistakes yourself. For example, if you had said:

> I have this code, but it's only printing the date that the user input and then stopping....

you *might* have looked at your code and wondered why that is the case. And then you might have noticed you have `Console.WriteLine(Date)` and gone a ha! And maybe, just maybe, the same for the `break`.

Comment: Definitely an answer. Not the answer the asker deserves, but it is the one he needs right now.